# wx.ComboBox hides behind other panels

Tags: combobox, wxpython, height, overlap

I have been working with wxPython for quite a while now. I have a pretty good handle on most objects, and I've been able to create panel layouts without issue for the most part.

What I'm trying to do here is to display two lists (combo boxes.) One represents the complete list of possible options (on the left) that the user may select and add to the list on the right. The functionality works just fine, but the objects themselves visually become obscured by other panels contained within the same tab of a wxNotebook object (see red rectangle on attached image.)

[image: Combo boxes become obscured by panel containing button]

The top panel is a composite of three panels. The first contains a combo box and some spacers. The second (middle) contains the buttons that allow the user to add/remove items. The third, like the first, is a combo box and some spacers. The middle panel scales fine, but I cannot adjust the height of the combo boxes.

I want the combo boxes to be the wx.CB_SIMPLE layout so that all options are displayed. Ideally, if the number of options exceeds the panel height, I would see a vertical scroll bar.

What would be the easiest way to accomplish this without losing the combo boxes behind other panels?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a need to have 3 panels nested inside of your notebook page. Instead I would create one panel with nested sizers. You can create one horizontal BoxSizer to hold all the widgets. Then inside of that, you can add the left combobox to the sizer. Next create a vertical sizer that you can put your buttons into (add, remove, clear).

Add that vertical sizer to your horizontal sizer. Now create your right combobox and add it to the horizontal sizer. Now you have the same setup or close to it and you won't have panels crossing over each other.